# cannot save settings under the server menu on Sonatype Nexus

Tags: nexus

I have Nexus up and running, I can setup users, roles, I've added the ldap settings, and everything seems to be working correctly.  However, I can't seem to change any of the settings under the "server" config (such as the smtp settings).  It simply doesn't save.  Could this be an OS permissions issue?  Where does the server save these settings?

Answer (score 0):

n/m - "known" bug: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-5989

(apparently serverfault doesn't count characters in a link toward the min)